# Prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli

Im new to MySQLi but my logic below seems sound. Im trying to copy clients from one database to another; but its not working. This is the DB Im copying -from-:

```
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| client            | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| telephone         | varchar(14)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| physical_address  | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email             | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| contact           | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Here is my PHP script:

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(0);

    date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Johannesburg');
    include('_cli_functions.php');

    echo "Starting conversion...\n";

    $billing_db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'billing');
    if ($billing_db->connect_error) {
        die('Billing db connection error');
    }
    else {
        echo "Connected to billing db\n";
    }

    $whmcs_db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'whmcs');
    if ($whmcs_db->connect_error) {
        die('WHMCS db connection error');
    }
    else {
        echo "Connected to WHMCS db\n";
    }

    if (!$client_result = $billing_db->query('SELECT id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(contact, " ", 1) AS firstname,
SUBSTRING(contact FROM LOCATE(" ",contact)+1) AS lastname,client,SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(contact_email), ";", 1) AS email, 
physical_address,telephone FROM clients ORDER BY id')
    ) {
        die("Error: " . $billing_db->error);
    }

    if ($client_result->num_rows == 0) {
        echo "No clients to convert\n";
    }
    elseif (!$client_insert_stmt = $whmcs_db->prepare('INSERT INTO tblclients (id,firstname,lastname,companyname,email,address1,country,
phonenumber,password,currency,datecreated) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,"ZA",?,?,1,"' . date('Y-m-d') . '")')
    ) {
        printf("Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $whmcs->error);
    }

    $client_insert_stmt->bind_param('isssssss', $client_data['id'], $client_data['firstname'], $client_data['lastname'],
                                    $client_data['client'], $client_data['email'], $client_data['physical_address'], $client_data['telephone'], $password);

    $count = 0;
    while ($client_data = $client_result->fetch_assoc()) {
// this is just for debugging
        echo $client_data['id'], $client_data['firstname'], $client_data['lastname'], $client_data['client'], $client_data['email'], $client_data['physical_address'], $client_data['telephone'], $password;
        $password = generatePassword();
        if (!$client_insert_stmt->execute()) {
            die("\n" . $client_insert_stmt->error . "\n");
        }

        $count++;
        show_status($count, $client_result->num_rows);
    }
    $client_insert_stmt->close();
    echo $client_result->num_rows . " clients processed.\n\n";
?>
```

However, here is my output:

```
Starting conversion...
Connected to billing db
Connected to WHMCS db
1BillyBobCompany inc.a@b.co.za 123 Whatever Avenue(000) 000-0000
Column 'firstname' cannot be null
```

As you can see, its outputting the info thats getting binded, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not an answer at all, but please indent your code with 4 spaces and please use curly braces for your `if` statements and drop those oneliners.

Comment: You are using `$client_data` before you set it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the `bind_param()` ouside the `while` loop where you define `$client_data`. Pop that line under the `echo` statement in the loop instead.

Comment: Thats done the trick, but I thought the point of this all was that I could bind once and it would assign the 'new' value of the variable each time its executes?

Comment: @SupaMonkey You're confusing "binding" with "preparing". The point of a prepared statement is twofold: 1)your input is taken as a literal string, so better protection against injection; and 2) you *prepare* a statement once, then *bind* and execute as many times as you want to. The binding IS the assigning of new values.